# ssh through java

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using java ssh tools to make an ssh connection to my school account and look for a file and then delete it.  However I am creating three functions to do the same thing but with different files,  I am looking for a way to do that at the same thing instead of doing one after the other.  Here is some code.  Basically I want to know if there is a way to do this all on one ssh connection or some kind of fork or multithreading.

```
public void updateinterval() {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = "***********";
        String host = "********";
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

        session.setPassword("*********");

        // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
        UserInfo userInfo = new SftpUserInfo();

        session.setUserInfo(userInfo);

        session.connect();

        // look for a file named feedinterval

        String checkfortimeupdate =
                "cd public_html/final;grep '-send' feedinterval";

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(checkfortimeupdate);

        // X Forwarding
        // channel.setXForwarding(true);

        // channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setInputStream(null);

        // channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

        // FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/tmp/stderr");
        // ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(fos);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                String returned = new String(tmp, 0, i);

                String argument = returned.substring(6);

                if (returned.contains("-send")) {

                    // if its there its calls the removeinterval function
                    // which removes the file it found
                    // by doing the same thing this function does but with a
                    // different ssh command

                    arduinoupdate hey = new arduinoupdate();

                    hey.removeinterval();

                    try {
                        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

                        String[] commands = {
                                "system.exe", "-send", argument };

                        Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
                    }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("UpdateInterval Closed exit-status: "
                        + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                /* Thread.sleep(1000); */
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: please take at least a few minutes to format your code correctly. Use the `{}` button on the editor and make sure your code is readable in the preview.

Comment: Can you format your code or remove unnecessary fragments?

Comment: Just as a side, I'd recommend factoring this function into small 1-4 line methods for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run multiple tasks perhaps [ExpectJ](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/) would work better for you. ExpectJ uses JSCH under the covers, so this may make your life easier.

```
final ExpectJ expectJ = new ExpectJ();
final Spawn spawn = expectJ.spawn("host", 22, "user", "pass");
spawn.send("cd public_html/final\n");
spawn.expect("someReturn");
...
spawn.send("exit\n");
spawn.expectClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by the commenters, better factor it out in separate functions.
Then is gets more clear how to reuse the same connection (i.e. [Session](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/?com.jcraft.jsch.Session.html)) for several commands.

```
public void updateInterval(Session s, String filename) {
    String checkfortimeupdate = "fgrep '-send' \"public_html/final/" + filename + "\"";

    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setCommand(checkfortimeupdate);

    channel.setInputStream(null);
    channel.setErrStream(System.err);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream(), encoding));

    channel.connect();

    eatOutput(in);

    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("UpdateInterval Closed exit-status: "
                           + channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
    }
    channel.disconnect();
}
```

Then put the reading from the BufferedReader (it has a `readLine` method) in the method `eatOutput`, and have another method which opens the session and calls three times the method shown here (with different file names), and closes the session again.

Answer (score 0):

In respect to the usage of ExpectJ,
which is the best library to use in machine critical production application for expect based functionality?

ExpectJ or [Expect4J](http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/) library? Though, both library uses the JSch underneath!
Or [Apache SSHD](http://mina.apache.org/sshd/index.html) - Client:

```
SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient(); PipedOutputStream PipedIn...?
```